# How to Detect if I am on a bbpress 'plugin' page?

Tags: bbpress

How can I check if I am on a forum page or forum post inside my theme. I am using the bbpress plugin (not standalone bbpress). There should be some conditional like is_bbpress() or something?

Answer (score 12):

Indeed, there is a function named `is_bbpress()`. Use the RC1 version, it was introduced in r3344.

Comment: I have the same question and when I try this, I get an error that says is_bbpress() is undefined.

Comment: Because that function doesn't exist in beta, it was added later on

Answer (score 1):

This page explains the is_bbpress() function. http://codex.bbpress.org/theme-compatibility/getting-started-in-modifying-the-main-bbpress-template

It also details another way which involves creating a new template which matches one of the key names for example forum.php. Than all forum pages will be loaded with that template rather than page.php, meaning you don't have to use is_bbpress() to test if it's a forum page anymore.