# Loading bbPress CSS file only on forum directory

Tags: css, bbpress

I added bbpress forum pluggin in my site to handle discussions, forum or comments. The bbPress CSS file is added to every page of my blog. Now, I want to load it only on forum directory to consider page speed. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If it means anything to you, your site loads fine, and I could be wrong but the bbpress css is only executed on bbpress pages

Comment: Every single millisecond counts. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles are enqueued in the function `enqueue_styles()` inside the file `/wp-content/plugins/bbpress/templates/default/bbpress-functions.php`.

It's a matter of using [`is_bbpress()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/24683/12615) and [`wp_dequeue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style). Only one of the styles is enqueued, but here we're removing all 3 possibilities.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bbpress_enqueue_wpse_87081', 15 );

function bbpress_enqueue_wpse_87081()
{
    // Check if bbpress exists
    if( !function_exists( 'is_bbpress' ) )
        return;

    if( !is_bbpress() )
    {
        wp_dequeue_style('bbp-child-bbpress');
        wp_dequeue_style('bbp-parent-bbpress');
        wp_dequeue_style('bbp-default-bbpress');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*try* this in your header

```
<?php
if(is_page_template('bbpress.php' 'forum.php' or whatever your forum template is)){
   echo '<link href="path/to/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
}
?>
```

the  `if(is_page_template)`
is supposed to load the css only on that page template.

OR

```
<?php
    if(is_page('forums')){
       echo '<link href="path/to/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: There is no bbpress template in my theme. It resides on plugin directory. Please check it out on http://www.pageantly.com.

Comment: What is your bbpress slug? /forum? /support?

Comment: The slug is /forums/

Comment: Yeah, I think it will work, perhaps. However, using that if statement I might have duplicated the css without unhooking the other one...

Comment: Find the file where the css is originally loaded, comment the lines out and duplicate the above to include all bbpress css links.

Comment: By doing so (commenting the page to eliminate the css), this might be overwritten during updates and will be overlooked. I need a simple solution that will never be overwritten during updates.

Comment: That will involve creating a plugin/custom function. You can try rolling with this until a new bbpress update comes out. Its minor editing. Or you can wait until someone else answers. If your need is immediate, then trying my solution should suffice for now.

Comment: I could be wrong** but unless the css is assigned to a function, hook or filter, you cant simply override it with another hook, function or filter. Some things require a manual edit.

Comment: I'll need to  install bbpress to look at how the css is loaded and I'd rather let someone who already uses bbpress to have a go at your request. Hang in the, im sure someone has the answer

Answer (score 0):

brasofilo's answer didn't work for me. After some digging around and changing it a bit I managed to get it working by removing '-bbpress' from the dequeue's. Note that I'm not sure if this is the proper solution.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bbpress_enqueue_wpse_87081', 15 );
function bbpress_enqueue_wpse_87081()
{
    // Check if bbpress exists
    if( !function_exists( 'is_bbpress' ) )
        return;

    if( !is_bbpress() )
    {
        wp_dequeue_style('bbp-child');
        wp_dequeue_style('bbp-parent');
        wp_dequeue_style('bbp-default');
    }
}
```